# how I can add 1 to a values of a column whit respect of 2 columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

there is a group called PERNO, each group if in row i col2=="a", I want to add row of i+1 to end of group of col3 with 1

```
      PERNO     col2      col3
        1         b         3
        1         d         3
        1         a         4
        1         d         5
        2         v         2
        2         a         3
        2         a         4
        2         x         4
        2         h         5
```

output

```
      PERNO     col2      col3
        1         b         3
        1         d         3
        1         a         4
        1         d         6
        2         v         2
        2         a         3
        2         a         4
        2         x         5
        2         h         6
```

in first group the forth row of col3 added by one because its next to row of col2==a

in second group the 2 last row also added by one

real data:

str(df)

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   153008 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ PERNO: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ loop : num  1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ TPURP: Factor w/ 23 levels "(1) Working at home (for pay)",..: 2 3 2 13 13 13 15 2 2 13 ...
```

dput(df)

```
structure(list(PERNO = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), loop = c(2, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2), TPURP = structure(c(2L, 2L, 22L, 15L, 15L, 15L), .Label = c("(1) Working at home (for pay)", 
"(2) All other home activities", "(3) Work/Job", "(4) All other activities at work", 
"(5) Attending class", "(6) All other activities at school", 
"(7) Change type of transportation/transfer", "(8) Dropped off passenger", 
"(9) Picked up passenger", "(10) Other, specify - transportation", 
"(11) Work/Business related", "(12) Service Private Vehicle", 
"(13) Routine Shopping", "(14) Shopping for major purchases", 
"(15) Household errands", "(16) Personal Business", "(17) Eat meal outside of home", 
"(18) Health care", "(19) Civic/Religious activities", "(20) Recreation/Entertainment", 
"(21) Visit friends/relative", "(24) Loop trip", "(97) Other, specify"
), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

where we have

```
loop==col3,     TPURP==col2    "a"== (24) Loop trip
```

Comment: Can you check my post with  your updated dataset

Comment: I  have a doubt that you also loaded `plyr`  package and the `mutate` is getting masked by the `plyr::mutate`.  Can you try `group_by(PERNO) %>% dplyr::mutate(col3 = ..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'PERNO', get the `cummax` of logical expression (`col2 == 'a'`), return the `lag` of it specifying 'n' as the number of 'a' elements in the 'col2' and add (`+`) with 'col3'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(PERNO) %>%
   mutate(col3 = col3 +lag(cummax(col2 == 'a'), n = sum(col2 == "a"), default = 0))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   PERNO [2]
#  PERNO col2   col3
#  <int> <chr> <dbl>
#1     1 b         3
#2     1 d         3
#3     1 a         4
#4     1 d         6
#5     2 v         2
#6     2 a         3
#7     2 a         4
#8     2 x         5
#9     2 h         6
```

---

Or another option is to find the position of the last occurrence of 'a', use `case_when` to add 1 after that position

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(PERNO) %>% 
  mutate(col3 = if('a' %in% col2) case_when(row_number() > 
         tail(which(col2 == 'a'), 1) ~
          col3 + 1L, TRUE ~ col3 ) else col3)
```

or avoid the `if/else` with a `pmax` condition

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(PERNO) %>%
   mutate(col3 = case_when(row_number() > pmin(n(), 
     tail(which(col2 == 'a'), 1)[1], na.rm = TRUE) ~ col3 + 1L,
         TRUE ~ col3))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[,   .I[.I > tail(.I[col2 == 'a'], 1)], PERNO]$V1
df1[i1, col3 := col3 + 1L]
```

#### Update

Using the OP's new dataset

```
df %>% 
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    group_by(PERNO) %>%
    mutate(loop = case_when(row_number() > pmin(n(), 
         tail(which(TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"), 1)[1], na.rm = TRUE) ~ loop + 1,
           TRUE ~ loop))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   PERNO [1]
#  PERNO  loop TPURP                        
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                        
#1     1     2 (2) All other home activities
#2     1     1 (2) All other home activities
#3     1     2 (24) Loop trip               
#4     1     3 (15) Household errands       
#5     1     3 (15) Household errands       
#6     1     3 (15) Household errands
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PERNO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    col2 = c("b", "d", "a", "d", "v", "a", "a", "x", "h"), col3 = c(3L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))


df9 %>% 
  group_by(PERNO) %>% 
  summarise(Sum = sum(grepl("(24) Loop trip", TPURP, fixed = TRUE)))
```

gives

```
PERNO   Sum
  <dbl> <int>
1     1   483
2     2   268
3     3    60
4     4    39
5     5    16
6     6    11
7     7     0
8     8     0
```

If we check the output with the OP's full data

```
fileN <- 'df.csv'
df <- read.csv(fileN, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

out <- df %>% 
     group_by(PERNO) %>%
     mutate(loop = case_when(row_number() > pmin(n(), 
                                                   tail(which(TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"), 1)[1],
                                                   na.rm = TRUE) ~ loop + 1L,
                          TRUE ~ loop))
```

-checking the output for the first 'PERNO' from the 'last' match of the string in 'loop' column

```
 df %>% 
    filter(PERNO == 1) %>% 
    select(TPURP, loop) %>% 
    filter(row_number() >= tail(which(TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"), 1)[1]) %>%
     pull(loop) %>% 
     head(10)
#[1] 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2

out %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    filter(PERNO == 1) %>%
    select(TPURP, loop) %>%
    filter(row_number() >= tail(which(TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"), 1)[1]) %>%
    pull(loop) %>% 
    head(10)
#[1] 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3
```

Notice, the values are adding 1

Comment: why it doesn't change col3 of my data at all?

Comment: @hghg Have you assigned `df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(PERNO) %>..`

Comment: yes I did , second one also gives me error: Error: `row_number() > tail(which(TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"), 1) ~ loop + 
    1L`, `TRUE ~ loop` must be length 0 or one, not 166

Comment: @hghg I think in the second one, the issue would be that there would be groups wiithout having any 'a'.  Here, I assumed that all groups have 'a'

Comment: I do not know why the first one doesn't work on my data, it doesn't change any thing

Comment: @hghg I did try the first one with a group having no 'a' and it is working fine.  Have you used `dplyr::lag` or is there other `lag` functiion from another package loaded

Comment: maybe! how I can check it? and updated second one also doesn't change any thing

Comment: @hghg  That is strange, may be something else is going on in your env.  It is working fine with the data i sbowed and also this data `structure(list(PERNO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    col2 = c("b", "d", "f", "d", "v", "a", "a", "x", "h"), col3 = c(3L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: I will put my data in question

Comment: @hghg Please use `dput`

Comment: @hghg Tried on your new data, and it is working too.  Note the 2s are changed to 3

Comment: It also work on my own dput data but why doesn't work in whole data set?

Comment: @hghg Do you have  `NA` elements (the code should work for that too0

Comment: @hghg It would be better if you provide an example that doesn't work because checking on data that works will not help in identifying the issue

Comment: @hghg But, if you check my code, it is working fine with the same `dput` data you showed

Comment: @hghg Do you have leading/lagging spaces.  in that case, `df %>% mutate(TPURP = trimws(TPURP))` and then apply the code or use `grepl`

Comment: it is weird, your code is working on my dput data, but I use the same code in whole data and it doesn't work

Comment: @hghg When you say that it doesn't work, did you meant that the rows that you subset is not also not changing or in other words, not at all changing any rows /

Comment: @hghg That is strange.  The only way it can occur is if the comparison `TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"` is FALSE or if it is TRUE only at the last row for each group.  Can you check `df %>% group_by(PERNO) %>% mutate(ind = TPURP == "(24) Loop trip")` Do you see any `TRUE`

Comment: @hghg Or get the `sum(df$TPURP == "(24) Loop trip")` and by group `df %>% group_by(PERNO) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"))`

Comment: Also, if it is not an exact match, use `grepl` `df %>% group_by(PERNO) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(grepl("(24) Loop trip", TPURP, fixed = TRUE)))`

Comment: some of them are true

Comment: could u plz give your email?

Comment: I put in current question

Comment: I sent some minutes ago

Comment: I wrote .R file and sent it

Comment: @hghg After applying the code, i find `sum(df$loop != out$loop)#
[1] 2363` many elements are changing

Comment: so what I can do?

Comment: @hghg What I meant is that for me, it is giving the correct output `df %>% filter(PERNO == 1) %>% select(TPURP, loop) %>% filter(row_number() >= tail(which(TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"), 1)[1]) %>% pull(loop) %>% head(10)
 [1] 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2#
out %>% ungroup %>% filter(PERNO == 1) %>% select(TPURP, loop) %>% filter(row_number() >= tail(which(TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"), 1)[1]) %>% pull(loop) %>% head(10)#
 [1] 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3`

Comment: @hghg What is the version of `dplyr` you have.  Can you try ithis on a fresh R sessoin?

Comment: @hghg I used `dplyr_0.8.3` and `R 3.6.0`

Comment: I have exactly same version

Comment: @hghg Can you check the output of the code I showed earlier.  Do you get the same value because it is exactly matching with the logic I used  `df %>% filter(PERNO == 1) %>% select(TPURP, loop) %>% filter(row_number() >= tail(which(TPURP == "(24) Loop trip"), 1)[1]) %>% pull(loop) %>% head(10)` and the same with `out`

Comment: I think its not complete , maybe u should put it in the answer

Comment: I got this : Adding missing grouping variables: `SAMPN`, `PERNO`
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

Comment: @hghg Please check my update.  It gives me the expected output

Comment: gives me this again  2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2

Comment: I want to try another way, I will define an indicator which is one after Loop in group PERNO then I will add this indicator by loop

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200156/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-how-i-can-add-1-to-a-values-of-a-column-whit-respe).